# What is the approximate probability that, among 45 components chosen at random from components of this type, 10 or more will last less than 900 hours?

Tags: probability

> Suppose that the lifetimes of components of a certain type have a $\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ distribution with $\mu=1000$ hours and $\sigma=100$ hours. What is the
>   approximate probability that, among 45 components chosen at random from components of this type, 10 or more will last less than 900 hours? (To make the
>   arithmetic easy, assume that $\Phi(-1) =1/6$.)

The answer is $0.21$.

I am learning by myself and have encountered this exercise.

where 's wrong?

${y-np\over \sqrt{npq}}<{10-7.5\over 2.5}$

$$Pr(y\geq 10)=1-Φ（1）=Φ(-1)=1/6\sim 0.15 $$

Comment: $p$ stands for probability, right?

Comment: How can it be more that 1?

Comment: sorry ,I dont type this μ,so i have to copy it ,now all right?

Comment: wow, how to type that beautiful sign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(y-np+0.5 #continuous correction
)/(npq^1/2)
<(9.5-7.5)/2.5
=0.8

so
result is   Pr(Y>9.5)=1-Φ（0.8）＝1-0.788=0.212

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- Let $X$ denote the lifetime of a component. Then:$$X<900\iff 0.01X-10<-1$$
  What can be said about the distribution of $0.01X-10$?
- Of $45$ components let $Y$ denote the number of components having a lifetime less than $900$. Then $Y$ has binomial distribution with parameters $n=45$ and $p=\Pr(X<900)$.

Comment: yes,I do the next step,where 's wrong? ; (y-np)/(npq^1/2)<(10-7.5)/2.5 ; Pr(y>=10)=1-Φ（1）=Φ(-1)=1/6~0.15

Comment: well,my book give a tip call "continuous correction",so i get the right ans,thx

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: @drhab Can you please go to full detail. I'm new at statistic.